# c macro for setting bits

Tags: c, macros

I have a program that compares variables from two structs and sets a bit accordingly for a bitmap variable. I have to compare each variables of the struct. No. of variables in reality are more for  each struct but for simplicity I took 3. I wanted to know if i can create a macro for comparing the variables and setting the bit in the bitmap accordingly.

```
#include<stdio.h>


struct num 
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

struct num1
{
   int d;
   int e;
   int f;
};

enum type
{
   val1 = 0,
   val2 = 1,
   val3 = 2,
};
int main()
{
  struct num obj1;
  struct num1 obj2;
  int bitmap = 0;

  if( obj1.a != obj2.d)
  {
      bitmap  = bitmap | val1;
  }
  if (obj1.b != obj2.e)
     bitmap = bitmap | val2;

  printf("bitmap - %d",bitmap);
  return 1;


}
```

can i declare a macro like...

```
#define CHECK(cond)
  if (!(cond))
    printf(" failed check at %x: %s",__LINE__, #cond);
    //set the bit accordingly

#undef CHECK
```

Comment: Certainly you can define macros to do things like that, but you need to use the "\" character as a continuation character at the end continued lines (including the first), and you don't want to do `#undef` right after the declaration since that will undefine the macro you just spent so much effort defining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a modicum of care, you can do it fairly easily.  You just need to identify what you're comparing and setting carefully, and pass them as macro parameters.  Example usage:

```
CHECK(obj1.a, obj2.d, bitmap, val1);
CHECK(obj1.b, obj2.e, bitmap, val2);
```

This assumes that `CHECK` is defined something like:

```
#define STRINGIFY(expr) #expr

#define CHECK(v1, v2, bitmap, bit) do \
    { if ((v1) != (v2)) \
         {   printf("failed check at %d: %s\n", __LINE__, STRINGIFY(v1 != v2)); \
             (bitmap) |= (1 << (bit)); \
         } \
    } while (0)
```

You can lay the macro out however you like, of course; I'm not entirely happy with that, but it isn't too awful.

#### Demo Code

Compilation and test run:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O3 -std=c99 xx.c -o xx && ./xx
failed check at 40: obj1.a != obj2.d
failed check at 42: obj1.c != obj2.f
bitmap - 5
$
```

Actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct num 
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

struct num1
{
   int d;
   int e;
   int f;
};

enum type
{
   val1 = 0,
   val2 = 1,
   val3 = 2,
};

#define STRINGIFY(expr) #expr

#define CHECK(v1, v2, bitmap, bit) do \
    { if ((v1) != (v2)) \
      {   printf("failed check at %d: %s\n", __LINE__, STRINGIFY(v1 != v2)); \
      (bitmap) |= (1 << (bit)); \
      } \
    } while (0)


int main(void)
{
    struct num  obj1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    struct num1 obj2 = { 2, 2, 4 };
    int bitmap = 0;

    CHECK(obj1.a, obj2.d, bitmap, val1);
    CHECK(obj1.b, obj2.e, bitmap, val2);
    CHECK(obj1.c, obj2.f, bitmap, val3);

    printf("bitmap - %X\n", bitmap);
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, this code relies on you matching the right elements and bit numbers in the invocations of the CHECK macro.

It's possible to devise more complex schemes using `offsetof()` etc and initialized arrays describing the data structures, etc, but you'd end up with a more complex system and little benefit.  In particular, the invocations can't reduce the parameter count much.  You could assume 'bitmap' is the variable.  You need to identify the two objects, so you'll specify 'obj1' and 'obj2'.  Somewhere along the line, you need to identify which fields are being compared and the bit to set.  That could be some single value (maybe the bit number), but you've still got 3 arguments (`CHECK(obj1, obj2, valN)` and the assumption about `bitmap`) or 4 arguments (`CHECK(obj1, obj2, bitmap, valN)` without the assumption about `bitmap`), but a lot of background complexity and probably a greater chance of getting it wrong.  If you can tinker with the code so that you have a single type instead of two types, etc, then you can make life easier with the hypothetical system, but it is still simpler to handle things the way shown in the working code, I think.

I concur with [gbulmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274815/gbulmer) that I probably wouldn't do things this way, but you did state that you had reduced the sizes of the structures dramatically (for which, thanks!) and it would become more enticing as the number of fields increases (but I'd only write out the comparisons for one pair of structure types once, in a single function).

You could also revise the macro to:

```
#define CHECK(cond, bitmap, bit) do \
    { if (cond) \
      {   printf("failed check at %d: %s\n", __LINE__, STRINGIFY(cond)); \
          (bitmap) |= (1 << (bit)); \
      } \
    } while (0)

CHECK(obj1.a != obj2.d, bitmap, val1);
...
CHECK((strcmp(obj3.str1, obj4.str) != 0), bitmap, val6);
```

where the last line shows that this would allow you to choose arbitrary comparisons, even if they contain commas.  Note the extra set of parentheses surrounding the call to `strcmp()`!

Comment: Believe me I tried this just few mins ago. yes i think this one is more elegant and straight forward. Instead of passing just field name i am now passing the enum value and the bitmap.. didn't try to run it yet. hope it works..

Comment: Make sure you got the latest version; there were a couple of hiccups en route to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that except you need to use backslash for multi-line macros

```
#ifndef CHECK
    #define CHECK(cond) \
    if (!(cond)) { \
      printf(" failed check at %x: %s",__LINE__, #cond); \
      //set the bit accordingly
    }
#endif /* CHECK */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get really fancy (and terse), you can use the concatenation operator.  I also recommend changing your structures around a little bit to have different naming conventions, though without knowing what you're trying to do with it, it's hard to say.  I also noticed in your bit field that you have one value that's 0; that won't tell you much when you try to look at that bit value.  If you OR 0 into anything, it remains unchanged.  Anyway, here's your program slightly re-written:

```
struct num {
   int x1; // formerly a/d
   int x2; // formerly b/e
   int x3; // formerly c/f
};

enum type {
   val1 = 1, // formerly 0
   val2 = 2, // formerly 1
   val3 = 4, // formerly 2
};

// CHECK uses the catenation operator (##) to construct obj1.x1, obj1.x2, etc.
#define CHECK(__num) {\
   if( obj1.x##__num != obj2.x##__num )\
     bitmap |= val##__num;\
}

void main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  struct num obj1;
  struct num obj2;
  int bitmap = 0;

   CHECK(1);
   CHECK(2);
   CHECK(3);
}
```

Comment: i was just going thru the ## operator and writing something similar to what you wrote.. you read my mind!

Comment: If you change the rules enough, it becomes easy?

Answer (score 0):

As a reasonable rule of thumb, when trying to do bit-arrays is C, there needs to be a number that can be used to index the bit.

You can either pass that bit number into the macro, or try to derive it.

Pretty much the only thing available at compile time or run time is the address of a field.
So you could use that.

There are a few questions to understand if it might work. 
For your structs:

1. Are all the fields in the same order? I.e. you can compare c with f, and not c with e?
2. Do all of the corresponding fields have the same type

Is the condition just equality? Each macro will have the condition wired in, so each condition needs a new macro.

If the answer to all is yes, then you could use the address:

```
#define CHECK(s1, f1, s2, f2) do \
    { if ((&s1.f1-&s1 != &s2.f2-&s2) || (sizeof(s1.f1)!=sizeof(s2.f2)) \
         || (s1.f1) != (s2.f2) \
         {   printf("failed check at %d: ", #s1 "." #f1 "!=" #s1 "." #f1 "\n", \
                                     __LINE__); \
             (shared_bitmap) |= (1 << (&s1.f1-&s1)); // test failed \
         } \
    } while (0)
```

I'm not too clear on whether it is a bitmap for all comparisons, or one per struct pair. I've assumed it is a bit map for all.

There is quite a lot of checking to ensure you haven't broken 'the two rules':

```
(&s1.f1-&s1 != &s2.f2-&s2) || (sizeof(s1.f1)!=sizeof(s2.f2))
```

If you are confident that the tests will be correct, without those constraints, just throw that part of the test away.

**WARNING** I have not compiled that code.

This becomes much simpler if the values are an array.

I probably wouldn't use it. It seems a bit too tricky to me :-)